# Java + ServerSocket + Firewall

Tags: java, sockets, firewall, serversocket

I've got a server written on Java with ServerSocket.

And I have a client that is over a corporative firewall that is blocking everything except common ports.

I've started server on SMTP port (#25).

The user with firewall connects to it and so far everything is ok.

Then the server processes ServerSocket.accept(). And as far as I understand it creates a socket on a random port (every time the port number is different). And fails because of a firewall.

My question is - how can I make ServerSocket.accept() to choose a port for a socket from my white-list? I understand that it will not suite for massive online, but I want to make one my friend to be able to connect to my server.

Is it possible? And how?

Comment: I think that you will require to use something like SOCKS on yor friend's side: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOCKS. Assuming that on your side there is no configuration problem in your home router, where you must allow to have outbound server traffic.

Answer (score 0):

server socket doesn't choose random port. it is the client socket which chose the random port. my guess is that your fire wall is smart and it knows to detect if the connection is approved by some sort of dpi (deep packet inspection).

if you want to mislead it, you can try to run data which looks like smtp in the first 2-3 packets and then switch to your protocol.

Another option it to use a kind of a connector outside the system, in this case both machines are clients which are connected through a 3rd client (there are many such proxies)

Comment: I disagree, @soulbuner assumption is right, the port defined is only used to establish the connection. After the accept a second random port, over the 1024 is used for the data transfer.

Comment: As a former developer of DPI engine I asure it is correct, you can use wireshark to record some http traffic for example and see. there are how ever some protocols which used multiple channels like FTP, but this is not the case.

Comment: Then one of us is not understanding the question properly because my experience is the same than @soulburner explains